# Google chart combo chart cannot custom multi vAxis

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I try to custom vertical axis max and min value in google chart but nothing change.
I follow references from https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart

```js
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', '実績（件数）');
  data.addColumn('number', '体調');

  data.addRows([['03/19',2,5],['03/20',3,4],['03/21',3,3]]);

  var materialOptions = {
    seriesType: 'bars',
    interpolateNulls: true,
    series: {
      0: {axis: '実績（件数）'},
      1: {axis: '体調', targetAxisIndex:1, type:'line'}
    },
    height: 400,
    vAxis: {
      0: {
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 5.5
      },
      1: {
        minValue: 1,
        maxValue: 6
      }
    }
  };
  var materialChart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(chartDiv);
  materialChart.draw(data, materialOptions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add isStacked: true like bellow

```js
vAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 5.5 }
isStacked: true,
```